# MediaPlayer - use ringtone volume instead of media volume

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

How can I set volume level from ringtone instead of media volume level on MediaPlayer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`setAudioStreamType(int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioStreamType(int)) to set the media type to type `STREAM_RING`, then it should use the ringer volume instead of the default `STREAM_MUSIC`.

Note that you must do this before the media is prepared, so you'll have to prepare it manually with `setDataSource` instead of using `MediaPlayer.create()`.

Comment: Is it possible to do the opposite? Meaning that phone calls ringtones will be played via the media STREAM_MUSIC ?

Answer (score 0):

Since Lollipop, `setAudioAttributes()` is to be used over `setAudioStreamType(int)`.

A catch that I had missed was that setAudioAttributes won't work if `MediaPlayer` was created as `MediaPlayer.create()`

Please refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51008956/10045546