# Playing sound as Media/Alarm/Ringtone?

Tags: java, android, ringtone, ringtonemanager

My app plays an alarm. In the Android Sound settings, this sound is controlled by the "Ring volume" slider and not the "Alarm volume" slider.  How can I change the sound to be controlled by the "Alarm volume"?

```
 public void doAlarm(){ 

    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);

    if (!r.isPlaying())
        r.play();
     }
```

I have tried using setAudioAttributes, but the result was that the "Media Volume" slider controlled the volume:

```
public void doAlarm(){

    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    mp.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM).build());
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found a solution: not using the `.create()` method. Instead use `.setDataSource()` and `.prepare()`. Code below:

```
public void ringAlarm() {

    Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
    if (alarmUri == null) {
        alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    }

    if (alarmUri == null) {
        Log.e("ringAlarm" , "alarmUri null. Unable to get default sound URI");
        return;
    }

    MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    // This is what sets the media type as alarm
    // Thus, the sound will be influenced by alarm volume
    mp.setAudioAttributes(new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                             .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM).build());

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), alarmUri);
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // To continuously loop the alarm sound
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}
```